# Inverse of the complex exponential function, considered as a multivariable function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

Consider the complex exponential function $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto e^z$. When identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the natural way, then $g$ can be considered as a transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

First, I want to concretely find $f(x, y)$ for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Next, consider the straight lines parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axis. How do their images regarding $f$ look like?

Finally, I want to show that $f$ (and therefore the exponential function $g$) are locally invertible, (meaning that for each $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a neighbourhood $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $U$ open, in which $f$ is bijective and therefore can be inverted), but that $f$ doesn't have a global inverse function.

**My attempt:** for $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$e^z = e^{a+bi} = e^a(\cos(b)+ i ºsin(b)) = e^a\cdot \cos(b) + i\cdot e^a\cdot \sin(b)$$

And therefore, I would assume that $f(x, y) = \pmatrix{e^x \cos(y) \cr e^x \sin(y)}$.

If I'm correct with this, I would assume that one could get the image of these straight lines by just fixing either $x$ or $y$, and seeing what happens: the image of these straight lines would then be $c \pmatrix{\cos(y) \cr \sin(y)}$ or $\pmatrix{c_1 e^x \cr c_2 e^x}$, with $c, c_1, c_2$ constant (because of the fixed other parameter), would they?

I don't really know how to approach the second part though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your work on the first parts is mostly correct, but you were wrong in taking both $\cos y$ and $\sin y$ outside the vector as $c$ for fixed $y$ (they're generally not equal). Also you could go one step further in answering "How do their images regarding $f$ look like?" more literally -- you've given formulas for these images; what do the curves given by these formulas look like?

Comment: Ok thanks, fixed that. Well, the images of the lines parallel to the $y$ axis are circles around $(0, 0)$ with radius $e^x$, are they? Because $\pmatrix{cos(y) \cr cos(sin(y)}$ parameterizes the unit circle if I recall correctly. And the lines parallel to the $x$-axis, well, $\pmatrix{c_1 \cr c_2}$ is just a vector $≠ 0$ (because $sin$ and $cos$ don't have common roots), and this vector is "stretched" by a positive value $e^x$, so these would look like straight lines with $(0, 0)$ in it's center but only going in one direction and not actually touching $(0, 0)$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Inverse function theorem. The jacobian of $f$ is $e^x\ne0$. This gives local invertibility. To show that $f$ is not a injective on $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y+2\,k\,\pi)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.